# MongoDB find slow with regex

Tags: mongodb

The system I currently develop on, uses MongoDB 2.4.4

I have a collection of users.

There is a combined index: `{ "LASTNAME" : 1 , "FIRSTNAME" : 1 , "EMAIL" : 1 , "CITY" : 1 , "STATUS" : 1}`
I also tried with single indexes, without a performance increase

The system contains 400.000 test records.

The query (Java debug from org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query):

```
{ "LASTNAME" : { "$regex" : "^Schm"}},
  Fields: { "FIRSTNAME" : 1 , "EMAIL" : 1 , "CITY" : 1 , "STATUS" : 1 ,"LASTNAME" : 1},
  Sort: { "LASTNAME" : 1 , "FIRSTNAME" : 1 , "EMAIL" : 1 , "CITY" : 1 , "STATUS" : 1}
```

performs within 16ms.That is fantastic.

This query is not shown in the MongoDB console (no debug information to post here).

But, I like to search not only starts with, it also should be case insensitive.

The query:

```
{ "LASTNAME" : { "$regex" : "^Schm" , "$options" : "i"}},
  Fields: { "FIRSTNAME" : 1 , "EMAIL" : 1 , "CITY" : 1 , "STATUS" : 1 , "LASTNAME" : 1},
  Sort: { "LASTNAME" : 1 , "FIRSTNAME" : 1 , "EMAIL" : 1 , "CITY" : 1 , "STATUS" : 1}
```

performs within 897ms. That is unacceptable slow.

Mongo Console shows this:

```
query: { query: { LASTNAME: /^Schm/i },
  orderby: { LASTNAME: 1, FIRSTNAME: 1, EMAIL: 1, CITY:1, STATUS: 1 }
} cursorid:1252405545564528 ntoreturn:25 ntoskip:0 nscanned:297651
keyUpdates:0 numYields: 1 locks(micros) r:1391715 nreturned:25 reslen:4422 897ms
```

As one can see. It's not the scanAndOrder problem that points onto index problems.

Then I tried to solve it the next way what fits the most scenarios (inserted from the user, lower case and upper case), but that is slower also.
My expectation was, that it performs thrice as long as the first query.

The query:

```
{ "$or" : [ { "LASTNAME" : { "$regex" : "^Schm"}} , { "LASTNAME" : { "$regex" : "^schm"}} , { "LASTNAME" : { "$regex" : "^SCHM"}}]},
  Fields: { "FIRSTNAME" : 1 , "EMAIL" : 1 , "CITY" : 1 , "STATUS" : 1 , "LASTNAME" : 1},
  Sort: { "LASTNAME" : 1 , "FIRSTNAME" : 1 , "EMAIL" : 1 , "CITY" : 1 , "STATUS" : 1}
```

performs within 1300ms. Nothing more to say.

MongoDB console:

```
query: { query: { $or: [ { LASTNAME: /^Schm/ }, { LASTNAME: /^schm/ }, { LASTNAME: /^SCHM/ } ] },
  orderby: { LASTNAME: 1, FIRSTNAME: 1, EMAIL: 1, CITY: 1, STATUS: 1 }
} cursorid:43560166842085 ntoreturn:25 ntoskip:0 nscanned:297651
keyUpdates:0 numYields: 1 locks(micros) r:1531168 nreturned:25 reslen:4422 1300ms
```

So, how can I search case insensitive that nearly has the speed of the first search?
Maximal 150ms!

Comment: As a side note, I have removed the Java tags since this question is only related to Mongo, not Java

Comment: Can you please post the `explain()` for your `$or` query

Comment: I don't know how, using Spring MongoTemplate. Currently thinking about switching to mongo-java-driver...

Comment: You would get the `explain()` from the mongo console, not from Spring

Comment: I now tested it directly on the mongo shell of version 2.4.5. The sort operation makes it so slow (without sort the or statement perfoms in 16ms): -> http://pastebin.com/Gd0LRPb7

Comment: That's what I figured was happening after I thought about it. Can you please post the exact same output but with the `sort()` for comparison?

Comment: The above pastebin is with sort... without sort -> http://pastebin.com/gVXu7nqJ   So, the search is fast with and without an or. so why is the sort on an or so slow?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33367/discussion-between-nabor-and-colin-morelli)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As soon as you add case insensitivity, you can no longer use an index. This is an important design concern when building an application that needs to have support for searching.

To overcome this, you should store an already-lowercased version of the last name in another field, and query against that case-sensitively (obviously translating all of your search queries to lowercase before passing them to Mongo).

**Edit**

It looks like text search has been added in 2.4. Read about it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/) and see if that will do what you need.

As a side note, if you are really concerned with performance (which, judging by your question, it sounds like you might be) you should really reconsider searching against your data storage engine. Consider an alternative search engine such as ElasticSearch (or a simple Lucene index) to keep search traffic off of your primary data store.

Comment: "As soon as you add case insensitivity, you can no longer use an index" <-- +1 for that. It is like people complaining that their SQL query is slow on dates when they use `trunc()`.

Comment: But then, why is the or solution so damn slow?

Comment: @Nabor Regardless of why your `$or` solution is so slow (which, I believe it's because Mongo is falling back to an index scan since you have given it 3 possible "roots" to search from), you should question whether or not it's worth your time anyway. Are you really going to construct an `$or` query with every valid permutation of casing for each letter in a query, as a way of avoiding a case insensitive search? That won't be any faster. Indexes or not.

Comment: The first line isn't totally true, it is as soon as you loose the prefixed anchor OR use case insensitivity that it cannot use the ability to effectively use an index. Good point the mention still

Comment: @Sammaye Which means the first line is true. There is no way in which you can use case insensitivity and still use an index in Mongo (without a text index). I didn't say it's the *only* way that you would be unable to use an index. Just that it is _a_ way

Comment: Don't understand it. The or statement is not case insensitive. I would assume, that MongoDB checks the index with three values (in this example) not with one. So my expectation is that it last 3 to 4 times longer than querying without that or.

Comment: I don't want to construct an `$or` for every possible combination. Only lowercase, uppercase, and how the user has asked for it. That is an or with 3 values instead asking for 1 value.

Comment: @Nabor Believe me, you're better off storing the name lowercased and indexing that. Then translate all of your queries to lowercase. That is, of course, if you are set on using Mongo for searching and not switching to an engine better suited for this type of task.

Comment: Storing lower case may be a good solution, but then I need to do this for every property that may be searchable. 7 to 10 dynamical additional fields and the handling of it... A lot of work

Comment: @Nabor And now you see why MongoDB is not (nor is it intended to be) a search engine.

Comment: @ColinMorelli: It is incorrect that an index is not used when you add case insensitivity.  An index is not used *efficiently*, so you end up with a full index scan (but not a full table scan).  This is mentioned in the: [`$regex` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/), and you should also see by looking at the `nscanned` (index keys) versus `nscannedobjects` (documents) for a case-insensitive or non-anchored regex.  Scanning 300000 index keys to find 25 is definitely inefficient, and the alternatives of lowercase search field or 2.4 text search are better.

Comment: @Stennie Fair point; however, I consider a _full index scan_ to be effectively not using your index. I understand that it _is_, but as a developer you shouldn't be "okay" with that. It's extremely expensive.

Comment: @ColinMorelli: A full index scan is definitely not using an index effectively, but is generally still better than a table scan of the full documents (which can be significantly worse if you need to page in unused documents to read them!).  Indeed you should not be OK with this approach for common queries unless you have a very small data set (or high patience).

Comment: normal Case-sensitive regex query does not use index effeciently. You can try the explain to see it ... But the po's specific case of regex it does use the index. Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and is unable to utilize case-insensitive indexes.